# Using node-cmd in React... Getting TypeError: exec is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

I'm using npm node-cmd in my react app and it is failing on cmd.get (sending commands to the terminal).

All my code works in vanilla html and javascript but I need it to work in React. I'm thinking my setup is wrong in react.

```
     import cmd from 'node-cmd';


     let projDir = result.substr(0, result.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
     let projFile = result.substr(result.lastIndexOf('/')+1);

     let copyFile = "cp '" + projFile + "' pproXML.gz";
     let unzip = "gunzip -d pproXML.gz";
     let rename = "mv pproXML pproXML.prproj";
     let targetXml = projDir + 'pproXML.prproj';  

     let cmdStr =
          "cd ..'" + projDir + "'\n" +
          copyFile + "\n" +
          unzip + "\n" +
          rename + "\n" +
          "ls";

     // FAILS HERE
     cmd.get(
          cmdStr,
          function(err, data, stderr){
               alert(data);
          }
```

I'm getting TypeError: exec is not a function

Comment: Can you post full stack trace, that should give you path where it is failing

Comment: How do I post full stack trace?

Comment: where are you getting `TypeError` in console of what

Answer (score 1):

`exec is not a function` tell me that things get wrong on `node-cmd`.

Just open the lib:
`var exec = require('child_process').exec;`

That line will never work from browser. Just try with a single `ls`

Comment: I'm not running this from a browser. I'm running in Adobe Premiere

Comment: I've tried with a single ls and I get the same error.  var exec is in a supporting file cmd.js

Comment: So this is certainly the same problem for Adobe... you cannot require things like `child_process`

Comment: It works for me in vanilla html and javascript - I just can't get it to work in react.