# Is Extendscript able to zip/unzip a file using File Object?

Tags: javascript, adobe, extendscript

I can't find a lot of documentation on File Object for extendscript and am wondering if I am able to zip/unzip a file using the File Object in extendscript.

Comment: [Here is docs for File Object](https://estk.aenhancers.com/3%20-%20File%20System%20Access/file-object.html). Short answer; no the File Object does not provide methods to zip/unzip a file.

Comment: Thank you - Is there by chance another way to do this without using Node? I'm trying to use node-cmd in React - unsuccessfully.  See:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56814225/using-node-cmd-in-react-getting-typeerror-exec-is-not-a-function

Comment: In what application are you trying to do this? AE for example has `system.callSystem(cmdLineToExecute);` http://docs.aenhancers.com/general/system/#system-callsystem

Comment: I'm writing this for PPro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows you can make a .BAT file from ExtendScript and run it at once. See my answer here: [How to use extendscript to open another application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63222557/how-to-use-extendscript-to-open-another-application/64122050#64122050)

Instead of:

`c:/Windows/notepad.exe`

there should be something like:

`unzip c:/temp/my_file.zip`

I suppose something similar can be done on MacOS via bash script or AppleScript.